# Почему ругается компоновщик? Ошибка: LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall Menus::mainMenu(void)"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В чём проблема? Проясните пожалуйста нубу. В первый раз создаю многофайловый проект.

declarations.h

```
struct Students
{
    int Course;
    int NumGroup;
};

struct Menus
{
    void mainMenu();
};

Menus Menu;
```

defMenus.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "declarations.h"

 void Menus::mainMenu() 
{
    system("pause");
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "defMenus.cpp"

int main() 
{
     Menu.mainMenu();
}
```

Ошибки:

```
Ошибка  LNK2005 "public: void __thiscall Menus::mainMenu(void)" (?mainMenu@Menus@@QAEXXZ) уже определен в defMenus.obj  Studs   D:\C++Project\Studs\Studs\main.obj  1   

Ошибка  LNK2005 "struct Menus Menu" (?Menu@@3UMenus@@A) уже определен в defMenus.obj    Studs   D:\C++Project\Studs\Studs\main.obj  1   

Ошибка  LNK1169 обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более  Studs   D:\C++Project\Studs\Debug\Studs.exe 1
```

Comment: Вы включаете .cpp через `#include`, значит, его содержимое компилятор видит дважды.

Comment: Ну и объявлять переменные в header'к нельзя, т. к. они будут как бы объявленными в любом файле, включающем header.

Comment: Запомните, `#include` — тупая текстовая подстановка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка вот в этом:

```
#include "defMenus.cpp"
```

Включайте заголовочный файл с объявлениями, но не с реализациями (определениями).